# HTML5 video re loading on switch and return to video tab; Samsung Stock Browser Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-video, samsung-browser

I'm experiencing a weird behavior with Samsung Stock Browser for Android with HTML5 Video; (not happening on Chrome Android and Safari IOS)

When the HTML5 video plays and the user switches tab, then returns to the said tab with HTML5 video, the video reloads and starts from the beginning; (this is after the video has played for 4-6 seconds btw)

I've used "*visibilitychange*" and "*window.onfocus / window.onblur*" to detect such events; I also placed traces on parts of the code where the video loads a URL to which its not being called when the situation is happens; Also placed traces on the video tag error listener to see if there are any but nothing shows up;

Are there any incident which this has happened to others? What could cause this?

TIA!